# How to clear URL params when using GET to submit to the same action in Yii

Tags: html, forms, yii

I have a html page with a search form which contains a textfield. we type value and hit search. results of search will be shown below. this is working fine using POST method.

But I would like to use GET, as i need the field params to be shown in url (for the purpose of bookmarking a search result).

When i tried using GET, each time when i submit the form the new field params gets added up to the previous URL. Its affecting the search results also.

eg: 1st time i searched with keyword='car'. the url was like this:

```
/index.php/deal/getDeals?Deal%5Bkeyword%5D=car&yt0=Search
```

then when i searched with keyword="bike" and the url was :

```
/index.php/deal/getDeals?Deal%5Bkeyword%5D=car&yt0=Search&Deal%5Bkeyword%5D=bike&yt0=Search
```

I assume this is because i am submitting to the same action.  I need  a way to clear the 1stURL params and display the new params in URL. Can anyone suggest a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set form attribute `action`

```
$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'method' => 'get',
    'action' => array('controller/action')
));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because the form has not set any default action, which is calling the same page you're currently viewing.

This way, the first time, the URL is

```
/index.php/deal/getDeals
```

And works fine, however, the second time, the URL is

```
/index.php/deal/getDeals?Deal%5Bkeyword%5D=car&yt0=Search
```

And it adds the form elements after that page

You can solve this by calling (I'm not sure if you're using normal or active forms, but this is the general idea)

```
echo CHtml::beginForm(array('getDeals'), 'GET');
```

By doing so, the URL will be always the same, without any search parameters